# noUiSlider throws an error during create

Tags: nouislider

When I try to instantiate I get the error: (Firefox & Chrome)
  Error: noUiSlider (11.1.0): create requires a single element, got: [object Object]

Here's how it's called ...

```
function kboBuildSlider(kboToFromParams) {
var slider = $("#kboAgeSlider");

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: [kboToFromParams.To, kboToFromParams.From],
    connect: true,
    range: {
        'min': kboToFromParams.Min,
        'max': kboToFromParams.Max
    }
});

kboAddColor();
```

}

The scripts are...

```
<script src="../jscripts/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jscripts-KBO/kbo-slider.js"></script>// my slider logic
<script src="../jscripts-KBO/kbo-actionpanel.js"></script> //the full ui logic
```

Thanks - Abbott

Answer (score 1):

`noUiSlider.create` takes a dom element, you are passing a jQuery object.

In your case, you can change `noUiSlider.create(slider, ...` to `noUiSlider.create(slider[0], ...`.